# Swift how can I make Multimap(Java)

Tags: ios, swift, multimap, swift-dictionary

I begin Swift and IOS development, so I'm very new to this, I make what I want in java (See example) but I can't find how to do in Swift
I want to make a dictionary on Swift , I know that I can make it like this

```
var dict = Dictionary<String, Array<String>>()

var s1 = "one"
var s2 = "two"
var s3 = "three"
var root = "numbers"
dict[root] = [s1,s2,s3]

for str in dict
{
    print(str.value)
}
```

But this isn't that I want. I make same thing in java like this

```
final TreeMultimap<String, String> third1000multi = TreeMultimap.create(Ordering.<String>natural(), Ordering.<String>natural());
for (Word w : third1000) {
            third1000multi.put(w.getType(), w.getWord());
        }
```

It must be create a key if there isn't a key like this , if there is key , it must add the value to the key. For example,

1. "choose" --> "choosing" (there isn't any key "choose" so create one and put it "choosing" value   choose = ["choosing"] )

2."choose"--> choosen (there is a key named " choose" so add this value in it. choose = ["choosing","choosen"]
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `Dictionary subscript(_:default:)` accessor.

```
var dict = [String:[String]]()

var words = [ "one", "two", "three"]
var root = "numbers"

for word in words {
    dict[root, default: []].append(word)
}
print(dict)
```

Or more closely to your Java code:

```
var third1000multi = [String:[String]]()
for w in third1000 {
    third1000multi[w.type, default: []].append(w.word)
}
```

Comment: That works so good , thanks a lot :) Can you explain what does this code exactly ?

Comment: Which part do you need explained?

Comment: "Accesses the element with the given key, or the specified default value, if the dictionary doesn’t contain the given key." I read this from the Apple Developer Documentation but I couldn't see when the new key created if given key isn't exist. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript

Comment: As part of returning the default value, the default value is assigned to the given key.